# Difference between onCreateView and onViewCreated in Fragment - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I know this question has been asked many times but just wanted to have some more clarity.

So I wanted to create a simple fragment with a button that should change the fragment when clicked - very simple and basic one.

hence I create a function, and called it on `onCreateView`. Nothing happeded.

Then I created `onViewCreated` after `onCreateView` and called the same function in it.

It Worked.

My Question is What exactly made it work ?

here is the code

```
class homeFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    hello()
}
 fun hello()
{
    val button = view?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_login)
              button?.setOnClickListener{
                  val action = homeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToLoginFragment()
                  findNavController().navigate(action)

            Toast.makeText(context,"wao",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It should work from `onCreateView` as well, post the code that you tried

Comment: I tried with the above hello() function, it didn't work.

Comment: But you are not calling it from `onCreateView`, also check your logcat and see if there are any errors

Comment: nope, no errors. Just the button does nothing :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments, you did something like this:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    hello() // the method has already returned a View, so this call is never reached.
}
```

So, when you call `hello()` in `onCreateView` after the return statement,
the method has no effect because of the return statement.

Since `onViewCreated` is called after the `onCreateView`,
the underlying `View` is no more `null` in your `hello` function.

If you still want to use `onCreateView`, you can do something like this:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    hello(fragmentView)
    return fragmentView
}

fun hello(buttonHolderView: View?) {
    val button = buttonHolderView?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_login)
    button?.setOnClickListener {
        val action = homeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToLoginFragment()
        findNavController().navigate(action)
        Toast.makeText(context, "wao", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it after the view was inflated :

Comment: override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        hello()
    }
        fun hello()
    {
    .......
            }
        }

    }

Comment: Can you add that with proper formatting in the question so I can answer as per that.

Comment: `override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        hello()
    }
        fun hello()
    {
       ....
              
            }
        }

    }
`

Comment: Yes, hence so again is there any alternate that can be done onCreateView or it has to be done onViewCreated ?

Comment: The answer is updated accordingly. Please accept if it helped :)

Comment: `   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        hello(fragmentView)
        return fragmentView
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to inflate the view before calling the function:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {        
        val fragmentHome = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        hello(fragmentHome)
        return fragmentHome;
    }
```

Change your hello function:

```
fun hello(view: View)
{
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working either

Comment: This won't work because the `hello` method still has a reference to `view?.findViewById` & not the `fragmentHome` variable that you've created, the view hasn't been inflated by the Fragment which is referenced in`hello()`.

Comment: @LNGC MIssed the parameter, it should work now

Comment: i am sorry didn't understand